# magento 1.5 index and add to cart slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I just installed a custom module (PISC VAT) onto my 1.5 magento store and all of a sudden the index page and also the add to cart functionality of the site is slow (as in taking more than 5 mins on a local setup).

Could someone please explain how I could debug the application in order to find out what's slowing it down?

Regards

Comment: HOw many items have you got in your database? like in for sale?

Comment: around 4000 products, but when I remove the module it works fine, it's only when the module is installed that the site goes so slow

Comment: Yea that is not allot of products either. There must be some indexing issues with the plugin. I have not used it before but what do other people say? The plugin must be doing something daft with the data. IMagaine you had 40k or 400k prodcuts. dammit.